# How do I concatenate the data in two columns but with only part of it in bold within the new column?

Tags: vba, excel

I have got as far as the VBA code below but I need to loop it so that keeps going for every row until there is no value in Column A:

```
Sub BoldText()

Dim Part1Len, Part2Len, DividerLen As Integer
Dim Divider As String

Part1Len = Len(Range("B4"))
Part2Len = Len(Range("C4"))
Divider = " :"
DividerLen = Len(Divider)
Range("E4") = Range("B4") & Range("C4")

With Range("E4").Characters(Start:=1, Length:=Part1Len).Font
    .FontStyle = "Bold"
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the range you wish to evaluate using a [`For Each`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278490.aspx) loop.

You can then use the row index, for each row you loop through.

```
Sub BoldText()
    Dim Part1Len, Part2Len, DividerLen As Integer
    Dim Divider As String
    Dim c As Range, cRow As Long

    For Each c In Range("E4:E" & lrow(1))
        cRow = c.Row
        Part1Len = Len(Range("B" & cRow))
        Part2Len = Len(Range("C" & cRow))
        Divider = " :"
        DividerLen = Len(Divider)
        c.Value = Range("B" & cRow) & Range("C" & cRow)

        With c.Characters(Start:=1, Length:=Part1Len).Font
            .FontStyle = "Bold"
        End With
    Next c
End Sub
```

**Edit:**

I realised you wanted the range to be dynamic, I've updated the code above, and you will just need to include this function:

```
Function lrow(ByVal colNum As Long) As Long
    lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, colNum).End(xlUp).Row
End Function
```

The code will now loop until it finds the last row in `Column A`.